# Multiple guests with static ip's on Debian host

Tags: virtualization, debian, kvm-virtualization

Let me be honest. You don't know ANYTHING about Debian except adding a user, change password, install packages etc. I have this Debian with KVM and using virt-manager.

My server has this IP: 88.198.52.250.

I have these two IP's for my two guests (Windows):

- 88.198.52.252
- 88.198.52.253

I have found this simple guide: http://blog.elsobrino.org/2008/03/08/howto-setup-a-network-bridge-under-debian/

But the server is unreachable whenever i reboot after inserting the data for bridge0 (br0).

I would be very happy if you guys could point me in the right direction. Please, if you need anymore information, please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

**Data:**

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   88.198.52.250
  broadcast 88.198.52.255
  netmask   255.255.255.224
  gateway   88.198.52.225

# default route to access subnet
up route add -net 88.198.52.224 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 88.198.52.225 eth0
```

**brctl show**

*Empty*

**ip addr list**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNO                                                                                                                                                             WN qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:61:86:2b:83:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 88.198.52.250/27 brd 88.198.52.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::4261:86ff:fe2b:83d2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**ip route show**

```
88.198.52.224/27 via 88.198.52.225 dev eth0
88.198.52.224/27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 88.198.52.250
default via 88.198.52.225 dev eth0
```

Comment: Contents of /etc/network/interfaces, output of brctl show, ip addr list, ip route show.

Comment: Thanks, Womble. I've updated the question according to your requests :)

Comment: There's no bridge configuration given.

Comment: No - that's my whole problem. Each Tine i configurere one, I'm losing my connection to the server. I'm probably doing it wrong. That's why I want help to set up a bridge :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is [being answered here](https://serverfault.com/questions/83591/adding-a-bridge-for-my-two-guests-in-debian-with-kvm).

The /etc/internet/interfaces ended up like this:

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

# device: br0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address   88.198.xxx.xxx
  broadcast 88.198.xxx.xxx
  netmask   255.255.255.224
  gateway   88.198.xxx.xxx
  bridge_ports eth0

# default route to access subnet
up route add -net 88.198.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 88.198.xxx.xxx br0
```