# Adding a bridge for my two guests in Debian with KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, bridge

I'm trying to add a two tap0 and a tap1 for my to guests. I'm running Debian with KVM.

Each time i restart the server after putting this in /etc/network/interfaces/ the server gets unreachable.

Why is this? Am I missing something?

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

# device: tap0
# device: tap1
auto tap0 tap1
iface tap0 inet manual
iface tap1 inet manual

# device: br0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address   88.198.xxx.xxx
  broadcast 88.198.xxx.xxx
  netmask   255.255.255.224
  gateway   88.198.xxx.xxx
  bridge_ports eth0 tap0 tap1

# default route to access subnet
up route add -net 88.198.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 88.198.xxx.xxx br0
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After adding this to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

# device: br0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address   88.198.xxx.xxx
  broadcast 88.198.xxx.xxx
  netmask   255.255.255.224
  gateway   88.198.xxx.xxx
  bridge_ports eth0

# default route to access subnet
up route add -net 88.198.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 88.198.xxx.xxx br0
```

It returns this

```
Reconfiguring network interfaces...if-up.d/mountnfs[eth0]: waiting for interface br0 before doing NFS mounts (warning).

Waiting for br0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 32 seconds).
done.
```

An `ifconfig` prints this:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:61:86:2b:83:d2
          inet addr:88.198.xxx.xxx Bcast:88.198.xxx.xxx Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::4261:86ff:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:17982 (17.5 KiB)  TX bytes:19858 (19.3 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:61:86:2b:83:d2
          inet6 addr: fe80::4261:86ff:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1245 errors:0 dropped:421488495 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:159089 (155.3 KiB)  TX bytes:123602 (120.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:249 Base address:0xc000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's going on with that route?  It shouldn't be necessary.  Apart from that, it looks like a reasonable config.  Have you tried removing the `tap0` and `tap1` interfaces from the config and leaving the bridge in place?

Comment: The route was there from the start. I didn't edit that part. I'll try removing those and I'll get back.

Comment: Hey again. I've updated the question. Now, I'm not going to restart the server before someone tells me if this is good or bad ;)

Comment: That did the trick. Now I can reboot without losing the connection...